# How to preg_replace content between {{ }}

Tags: php, preg-replace

The following is my code to replace the content between `{{ }}`. For example I use {{example}} to load a custom text from db to replace the content in html output. This works well but at times it does not and I am unsure why. It maybe in the same line if I use two {{one}} and {{two}} .. so I thought maybe I am doing the `preg_replace` wrong.

```
function translate($tagname){
   global $$tagname;
   return $$tagname;
}

function replaceTags($body){
   $body = preg_replace('!{{(.*?)}}!Uei', "''.translate('$1').''", $body);
   return $body;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this construct: `"''.translate('$1').''"`... What is it meant to result in? I'd say it results in a literal string like that: `''.translate('$1').''` which certainly is not what you want.

Comment: @arkascha: That's why he uses `e` modifier, which causes it to evaluate as PHP code.

Comment: @hynner sorry, can't follow there. _What_ should be interpreted as php code?

Comment: It might not work if you have multiline strings. You need to add a modifier for that as well. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: @arkascha: See [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for `e` modifier

Comment: @hynner That modifier is not the issue, I very well understand what it does. But still the result would be what I wrote above: that simply is what php would output for that argument. The quoting format of that argument string is nonsense.

Comment: I _think_ what you are looking for is this as second argument: `"translate('$1')"`, but I did not try myself.

Comment: Also, you know `preg_replace()` only replaces once right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should drop the `U` modifier, as it will turn your ungreedy `(.*?)` greedy, and that is not what you want.

Also, the `e` modifier was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead:

```
$firstName = 'Jane';
$lastName = 'Doe';

function translate($tagname){
    global $$tagname;
    return $$tagname;
}

function translateMatch($matches) {
    return translate($matches[1]);
}

function replaceTags($body){
    $body = preg_replace_callback('!{{(.*?)}}!i', 'translateMatch', $body);
    return $body;
}

echo replaceTags("Hello, {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!"), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Hello, Jane Doe!
```

Comment: thats perfect! I did not check for the updates on the deprecated e. Thank You.